# After stretching faces, materials are zoomed in and not exact

Tags: faces

[image]

only after stretching the faces out of other materials, the materials in Unity won't appear exact.  they're zoomed in and offset.  how do i fix this as opposed to regular cubes?

Comment: did you already unwrapped? (after stretching)

Comment: Yes I did.  A few times

Comment: May be the UV map doesn't count for your texture type in Unity. Try a 3D texture type instead of sprite.

Comment: It's doing the same thing in Blender, too.  Unfortunately I do not see a way to add an image as a comment to show you.  But it's doing it in the stretched faced on the sides